# Proof of Hurewicz' thm. in Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm having trouble understanding the last part of Hatcher's proof of Hurewicz' theorem. (It's on page 367, thm. 4.32).

We want to show, that a cellular boundary map: $d:H_{n+1}(X^{n+1},X^n) \rightarrow H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})$ is a map $\oplus_\beta \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \oplus_\alpha \mathbb{Z}$, where $X$ only has cells in dimensions $n$ and $n+1$ and is given by $(\bigvee_\alpha S_\alpha ^n )\bigcup_\beta e^{n+1}_\beta.$

The argument goes like this:

"$d$ [is a map $\oplus_\beta \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \oplus_\alpha \mathbb{Z}$] since for each cell $e_\beta ^{n+1}$, the coefficients of $de_\beta ^{n+1}$ are the degrees of the compositions $q_\alpha \phi_\beta$ where $q_\alpha$ collapses all n-cells except $e_\alpha ^n$ to a point, and the isomorphism $\pi_n (S^n) \approx \mathbb{Z}$ in corollary 4.25 us given by degree."

Any help or ideas would be welcome :)

Comment: Sorry, what are $S^n_\alpha$ end $e^n_\beta$? I have some guesses, but..

Comment: Hi there! $S^n _\alpha$ is an n-sphere and $e^{n+1}_\beta $ is a cell of dimension $n+1$, which is homeomorphic to an open n+1-disc. $e^n _\alpha$ I guess is the $S^n _\alpha$ without the common point from $(\bigvee_\alpha S^n _\alpha)$.

Comment: The formula $d_n(e_\beta)=\sum_\alpha d_{\beta\alpha}e_\alpha$ where $d_{\beta\alpha}$ is the degree of the composition $q_\alpha\phi_\beta$ is explained in the section about cellular homology starting at page 137.

Comment: I also have some troubles in identify the boundaru map and the cellular boundary map.

Comment: we have to show that d and round maps isomorphisc elements to isomorphisc elements.